# SQL Server 2008 Xml Issue With Xml Escape Characters

Tags: sql-server, xml

Our current Point of Sale system executes too many queries in nested transactions that leave duplicated or partial data in place. I changed the entire thing to a single stored procedure where all sale item data is passed in as Xml, iterated through in a temp table, and saved to the database, then committed. However, SQL rejects special characters in the xml.

For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <list>
     <item>
         <objectid>bd99fcb6-3031-48b7-9a71-5f8cefe0a614</objectid>
         <amount>50.00</amount>
         <fee>1.50</fee>
         <waivedfee>0.00</waivedfee>
         <tax>0.00</tax>
         <name>TEST &amp; TEST PERSON</name>
         <payeeid>197</payeeid>
         <accountnumber>5398520352</accountnumber>
         <checknumber />
         <comedreceiptnumber />
         <isexpedited>0</isexpedited>
         <echeckrefnumber />
    </item>
</list>
```

Fails. It tells me that there is an illegal character where `&amp;` is located. I don't know why. It's escaped properly with `&amp;`. I can't find any solutions online, anywhere. Everywhere people tell me to replace & with `&amp;` - which is what I am doing!

Comment: For reference, this didn't parse the "code" bbcode properly. I am escaping special characters properly. An ampersand is written as ampersand+amp+semi-colon as appropriate. Yet Sql is rejecting that as an illegal character.

Comment: I tried changing encoding to UTF-8. Interestingly enough, this works perfectly if I execute it in sql server management studio (declare blah blah = my xml, select from my xml) but fails from C#. Even more odd, Sql Server Profiler can't seem to capture the query so I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: you need to post your c# code

Comment: `saleParameters.Add(new DbParam("@BC_Xml", BC_Xml != null ? BC_Xml : (object)(DBNull.Value), DbType.Xml));`

Comment: I've tried it as a string, with or without specifying datatype xml, with UTF-8, 16, ASCII, default (Windows-24 something)

Comment: This is definitely something with C#. Executing the stored procedure through sql server management studio with that exact data (UTF-8) works correctly. It fails if sent via C#. If only I could get Profiler to see the query!

Comment: Try AddWithValue instead of Add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. UTF-16 is correct. That Xml is fine. There was a final piece of xml, the ledgers, that were just plain strings with no encoding and no escaping special characters. Once I corrected that it all worked.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `XML PATH('')`, it will encode the special characters for you.

```
SELECT 'TEST & TEST PERSON' FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not trying to construct xml in Sql Server. I am trying to find out why Sql is rejecting Xml written from an outside source and passed to the command as a SqlXml object.

Comment: @Darsithis it could be a character encoding issue or an illegal character. Also, what is the data type of the column in question?

Comment: Hi Donal. The data type is `nvarchar(200)`. That fragment of xml is passed in as SqlXml to a parameter of XML. I iterate through all items as `FROM @BC_xml.nodes('list/item') AS item([Item])`

Comment: I suggest you use the XML data type, instead of nvarchar.

Comment: I can't change all of our sale tables to no longer use nvarchar. If you're referring to the parameter in the stored procedure, that is type XML